# How get session values from outside the page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

Is it possible to get the session value from out side the page context ? is a vb.net class ?

Answer (score 3):

Try [System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a class like this (example has only one property but you can set the ones you need)

```
Public Class MySession

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Current() As MySession
        Get
            Dim session As MySession = DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Session("__MySession__"), MySession)
            If session Is Nothing Then
                session = New MySession()
                HttpContext.Current.Session("__MySession__") = session
            End If
            Return session
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property IsAuthenticated As Boolean
End Class
```

And using this like so

```
    <%
       If MySession.Current.IsAuthenticated Then
    %>
```